# Legendre Transform of C1 function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

If $f:R \to R$ is a $C^1$ and strictly convex function with superlinear growth (i.e $ \lim_{|p|\to \infty}f(p)/|p| = \infty $),then what can we say about $f^*$ ?. will it be $C^1$ ?

Comment: The body of your Question should be used to give a clearer statement of the problem you want help with.  You've introduced $f^*$ without saying explicitly that it is the Legendre transform of $f$, nor that you *assume* its existence as part of the hypothesis.  Obviously these sorts of details make a difference in "what can we say".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f^*(p) = \max_x \{px - f(x)\}$ so $p=f'(x)$ and 
$$f^*(p) = p(f')^{-1}(p) - f((f')^{-1}(p)).$$ 
[Note $(f')^{-1}$ exists because $f$ is strictly convex, so $f'$ is strictly increasing.]

Here are a few more details: Write $g=(f')^{-1}$ so that $f^*(p) = pg(p)-f(g(p))$. Then

$$f^*(p+h)-f^*(p) = hg(p+h) + p(g(p+h)-g(p)) - (f(g(p+h))-f(g(p)) ).$$

By a Taylor expansion

$$f(g(p+h))-f(g(p)) = f'(g(p))(g(p+h) - g(p)) + o(h)= p(g(p+h)-g(p)) + o(h).$$

Plugging this in above we get

$$f^*(p+h) - f^*(p) = hg(p+h) + o(h).$$

Dividing by $h$ and sending $h\to 0$ we get that $(f^*)'$ exists and $(f^*)'(p) = g(p)$, so $f^*$ is $C^1$.

Comment: But  inverse of $(f')$ need not be C1 as f' can be only continuous.So the formula you derived does not imply f* is C1. This is where I am struck

Comment: Use the formula to show that $(f^*)'(p) = (f')^{-1}(p)$, which is continuous.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting it. Please explain

Comment: Assume for the moment that $f$ is $C^2$ and differentiate the formula for $f^*$. What do you get?

Comment: If f is C2 the result is true. But it's given f is only C1. How to prove the result for f which is just C1. Do we need passing to the limit kind of argument??

Comment: Yes, either approximate $f$ by a sequence of smooth functions and pass to the limit, or compute $(f^*)'$ directly from first principles with a difference quotient and you should get $(f^*)'=(f')^{-1}$.

Comment: I added a few more details.

Comment: Nice proof..thank you so much